# Google Calendar sync works only when Google Calendar app is uninstalled

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sync, google-calendar

I couldn't get Google Calendar to sync on my Galaxy S3 (with web version of Google Calendar). I did all things recommended on [this help page](https://support.google.com/calendar/troubleshooter/2819319) but it didn't help. I also tried removing Google account from the phone and adding it again.

However, during one of the reinstalls (as recommended in Google help page) I suddenly got a notification about an event in my calendar that was created in the web version.
The sync worked perfectly fine when the Google Calendar App was **removed** from my phone. When "Google Calendar App" was *uninstalled* the pre-installed "S Planner" showed me the notification because the sync kicked in.

I rechecked it both ways from Android app to the web version and vice versa.

I prefer [Google Calendar app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar) to "S Planner" but this issue renders Google Calendar app unusable.

I also sent feedback message from the app.

Edit to add: it worked fine until one of the updates of Google Calendar.

*Update:* user RossC suggested to disable S Planner and test sync, but unfortunately I can't disable it (see screenshot).
Disabling related applications (with words calendar, samsung and sync in the title) did not help.

[image: S Planner app info. Cropped screenshot]

[full screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHyb4.jpg)

Comment: Have you disabled SPlanner and tried it? Works fine here on an S3, S4 and S5 no bothers, once synch calendar is enabled in Accounts & Synch settings under your Google account.

Comment: @RossC Unfortunately, S Planner cannot be turned off without rooting, but app called "Samsung Calendar SyncAdapter" can be turned off. I will try that later, as I have to go right now. It's weird that everything else but the calendar (Contacts, e-mail) works fine.

Comment: You can't uninstall it, but you CAN disable it. I've tried it on 3 samsung devices. Go to the app info and hit 'Disable'. It SHOULD work fine for you. I can only go on the devices I have here. That said, Samsung do some weird stuff with their bloatware so I wouldn't be surprised at all if you can't.

Comment: I can't disable it. The button "Turn off" is disabled. I added a screenshot in the post. PS Disabling related applications didn't help.

Comment: This moves us back to Google calendar, but did you clear the cache? Select Calendar Storage. (If you don't see 'Calendar Storage,' press < Menu > again, then select Filter > All. On some devices, you won't see 'Calendar Storage.') Select Clear data. Answer OK when prompted.

Comment: @LivedWithOtters This advice is on the Google help page that I linked. I've gone through all these several times. I wouldn't have posted this if I didn't try all things suggested on the official manual.

Comment: @AndreyRybak sorry. The link came up as a walk-though of steps and I was too lazy to jump through each hoop to see if it was on your list. I'd been able to use the cache clear in the past to sort out odd google calendar issues.  In terms of diagnosing the problem, what happens when you throw a third calendar app into the mix? I'm thinking it might help us chase down if the problem is the google app or sPlanner.  Worst case, you might be able to find another calendar app (better than SP) that *does* work if GC won't.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and root your phone and download an app such as App Master from the app store to uninstall SPlanner altogether, as this would remove all of the Samsung calendar syncing issues you are having (hopefully - don't quote me but this worked for a friend of mine when he was having issues with his calendar syncing).  Hope this is of some help :)